# How to change boot camp partition if is set?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I had a mistake in windows 7 in my mac. I want to change the size of the partition of my hard drive to my windows 7. I know how to use boot camp but how do I change the windows 7 partition? I don't really understand the other websites instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a tool such as Paragon.  That way you don't have to go through the backup, delete, create process.

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/camptune/

Check out his article as well...

http://guides.macrumors.com/Extend_or_Resize_Boot_Camp_Partition

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your forte is not computers, this is not the best method, nor the fastest by any stretch; in fact it could possibly be the slowest way to do it. But it will work.

- boot into windows
- start migration assistant and copy all your settings and apps and docs to an external HD
- Go back to osx
- Delete w7 partition
- run bootcamp assistant.
- redownload the Windows Support files if you lost them (important)
- choose new partiton size
- reinstall windows
- reinstall Windows support (apple drivers)
- run migration assistant again and copy all your settings and apps and docs back.

There are other ways to do it (buying Paragon Partition Manager for instance) but this way its slow but free and almost impossible to screw up your computer.